# Can you have an Ultegra crank arm on the one side and a 105 crank arm on the other side

Tags: crankset

I have an Ultegra groupset, but I also have a 105 left crank that has a power meter. Can you mix these two? I don't care about the weight difference, only talking about a geometry point of view. My left shoe and right shoe's cleats are in exactly the same position, but my left side shoe (at the contact point of cleat and shoe) is against the crank arm?

Comment: Have you changed the meter crank recently? Did the shoes rub before?

Comment: Yes new left crank. No didn't rub before. Gabriel C.

Comment: Do keep in mind that it's not that unusual to have cranks of different length on one side vs the other.  This is often done when a person has one leg shorter than the other.

Comment: No problem in that marriage, except for different lengths of cranks of course. You can marry left and right from Dura-Ace to 105 and even lower. The right crank with the rings determines the compatibility to the cassette. and the chain.

Comment: Silly question - are they the same length?  Measure them or read the length off the stamping.

Comment: Have you tweaked your cleat position at all?  Compare left for right, perhaps even take a photo of each, flip one, and overlay them on screen.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, 105 and Ultegra components are largely compatible but it depends on the exact model numbers. Its best to check Shimano's compatibility charts.

I myself have a 105 crank on the left and an Ultegra on the right as the bump in my left Ultegra power meter crank won't clear my chainstay. They're both Hollow Tech II which means they're compatible.