# Would a Shimano 105 R7000 left side crank fit on an Utegra 6800 crankset?

Tags: shimano

I'm looking at getting a left side crank power meter and was wondering would the various shimano left cranks available with power meters fit with the existing Ultegra 6800 crankset I have? The 105 or even dura ace. Thanks

Comment: We have quite a few similar questions. The answer is the same, the left crank is independent and the interface universal (among Hollowtech || cranksetes), you can mix various left crsnks freely.

Comment: This one has 105 and Ultegra https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60274/can-you-have-an-ultegra-crank-arm-on-the-one-side-and-a-105-crank-arm-on-the-oth?rq=1 Another similar, but there are more https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24798/can-i-fit-a-105-crank-arm-stages-to-a-claris-2400-crankset?rq=1

Comment: Is the Q-factor any different between models and generations? I would expect Shimano to have slightly tweaked the Q-factors (perhaps narrower for race-oriented DA etc)

Comment: @MaplePanda IIRC, the reported Q-factor and chainline should be identical among the road Hollowtech II cranksets. GRX (gravel groupset) have 2.5mm wider chainline, and slightly wider Q-factor also.

Comment: @WeiwenNg the GRX chainsets are 3.4mm wider chainline, according to the Shimano specs. However the FD is 2.5m wider. No idea why. Q-Factor is 5mm more.

Comment: @Weiwen Ng Very interesting! You would think Shimano would tweak it as bike fit ideologies change over time. Good to know though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the left crank arm of your choice from the Hollowtech II road series. (105, Ultegra, DA)

It is quite commonly done, especially using a newer generation arm on an older chainset where the older style is no longer available.

Comment: Yeah, you can mix+match according to the Shimano compatibility chart. The 11s Ultegra + 105 left cranks are hollow forged whereas only the 105 drive side crank is hollow forged. Bonded cranks have a history of cracking+breaking. So I use a Frankenstein Ultegra left side + Stages power meter, 105 drive side and Dura Ace rings.

Comment: I have never seen these bonded cranks break. What kind of animal are you @Olsonist ?

Comment: A worried Clydesdale. https://www.bikeradar.com/features/shimano-crank-failure/

Comment: I'd hardly call that a worry especially in the context of Shimano replacing it even out of warranty plus was clearly damaged for some time before obvious failure. Don't live your life in fear.